# Need a specific part of a user input

Tags: javascript, regex, input, parentheses

It seems that I need a code that works the same as

```
var inPar = userIn.substring(userArray.lastIndexOf("(")+2, userArray.lastIndexOf(")")+2);
```

...which returns NO3)   when the user inputs the chemical formula Cu(NO3)2.

The current code (above) isn't dynamic at all, as it also has to return NO3) if the user enters, say H(NO3)2 or just (NO3)2.

I take it that a regex be the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Depends. What's the range of compounds that the user can enter? Anything? And why do you want the parenthesis in your results?

Comment: As of right now, yes, they can enter anything, although my code only works for one set of parentheses currently. I want the parentheses, as I have the ")" signifying the end of a while statement, which in turn gets the weight of everything with the ().

Comment: If all you're looking for is "something inside parantheses", then Mixthos' code works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should do the same:

```
var inPar = userIn.replace(/^.*\((.*\)).*$/, '$1');
```

I don't understand much about chemical formulas, so I don't know what a more dynamic approach should look like. Sorry.

Comment: Why not `/\((.*)\)/`? No need to search from beginning to end.

Comment: Also, `replace` seems like a weird way to do it. Why not `/\((.*)\)/.exec(userIn)[1]`?

Comment: String.replace replaces all occurrences of the given pattern. In order to remove the parts outside of the brackets from the result, you'd have to match them.

Comment: @Rygh2014, I'm not sure how the ')' signifies the end of a while statement in your program, but perhaps you should consider refactoring it to avoid this quixotic approach. Also, the edit to Mixthos' post includes the paranthesis.

Comment: @LonelyWebCrawler: You're right, exec would be the better way to do it.

Comment: @LonelyWebCrawler: I agree, I might end up changing it, as it may not be the cleanest may of doing things.  The ) isn't stopping the while statement, but rather is just used in a if statement, so I had something to tell the code when to stop adding the elements masses inside the parentheses.